# I would like to know whether expectation maximization is relevant to cost optimization imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I have a cost matrix which has probability confusion matrix

Here is the cost
predict good-actually good: 0
predict good-actually bad: 3 consequence points (negative)
predict bad-actually bad: 0
predict bad-actually good: 1 consequence points (negative)

I'm trying to improve this model - I already added the confusion matrix. I am wondering if the model could be improved by having reward for positive reward points for predict good-actually good. I am using the german data set but it says nothing about actual profit. It does have the credit amount but I am not sure how it relates to the cost table in the first place. Is the best I can do just adding a confusion matrix based on predicted outcomes? I can't seem to fathom what else is possible. Any direction would be appreciated. As you can tell, I'm pretty new to all this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an observation. You have a binary classification setting, meaning there are two classes. If the accuracy is 50%, it means you classified 50% of the data right and 50 wrong. That means no information gain. That means it is the same as if you flipped a coin. Now if your accuracy is anything below 50%, say like 40%, it means you predicted 60% wrong! it means you somehow deliberately avoided predicting them right, so if you just flip your prediction labels, then you are predicting 60% right! In your confusion matrix, your accuracy is zero! it means you are purposefully predicting everything wrong, so just flip your labels, and your accuracy will be 100%.

Side note : The confusion matrix is never improving your model, it merely provides insight on your performance. Also if you are getting an accuracy of 100%, it means you are validating on your training set. Unless you have very good reason for that, use cross-validation. You can google : Confusion matrix, accuracy score, precision, recall, cross validation, kfold for more insight.